# r-login.wordpress.com occasionally redirects to mysite.wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Occasionally whilst login in or even viewing a recently transfered site. This pops in, like a virus almost and it forces the old site content to display:

r-login.wordpress.com

Note this site is hosted on a separate domain. We just transferred the Domain name from wordpress to this new host. I went through the full process of using a script that removes an instant of the old domain from it. I had the wordpress template working fine but this is weird.

I have already blocked several 302 temp redirects with .httpaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.wordpress.com//$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com/wp-admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.wordpress.com/wp-admin//$1 [L,R=301]
```

I am also defining the wp home page and domain in a couple of spots.

If I clean the cache it seems to work but then something else happens. Its strange both the admin and sit are fine then something happens to show the old wordpress.com content.

//-- UPDATE --//

The issue I think is mysite.com is redirecting to the still existing mysite.wordpress.com when you try to get widgets or interact with wordpress.com, even viewing the wordpress.com site. I can clear my cache and it is fine until I interact with wordpress.com in any manner.

Then the wp-login.php or any part of the site redirects to mysite.wordpress.com, I can see the r-login.wordpress.com redirection in progress.

Now the issue I face is my business is worried about cancelling the mysite.wordpress.com site?

Any advice please!

Answer (score 0):

check your database hasn't got the domain added to `wp_options` or something similar.

Use PHPMyAdmin or a [Serialized Search and Replace Tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to replace `http://www.olddoamin.com` with `http://www.newdomain.com`.

Comment: Sorry if you read my post, I mentioned have done that. Its not the issue, it seems to be around the remote login process they use and it is attached it with the still live mysite.wordpress.com